# Unwanted vertical spacing between two <div> elements (one of them contains a <iframe> element)

Tags: html, css, iframe, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with unwanted vertical spacing between two  elements. One of them contains a  element, it seems to me that it gets stuck there.
However, the situation only occurs on larger screens (> 15 ") while on small ones it is ok. The larger the screen size, the larger the spacing. Help please I'm in dead end.

Code:

```
  <p class="w3-text-grey"><b><i>Zadatak 3.</i></b>
            Ispitati konvergenciju funkcionalnog niza \( f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n^2+x^2}\).
            </p>
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" >
              <iframe scrolling="no" title="Vežba 5" src="https://www.geogebra.org/material/iframe/id/e6jpyxer/width/1580/height/871/border/888888/sfsb/true/smb/false/stb/false/stbh/false/ai/false/asb/false/sri/false/rc/false/ld/false/sdz/false/ctl/false" style="border:0px; max-width:1000px; max-height:558px" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
            </div>
            <!--Here is the unwanted spacing! -->
            <div class="container-fluid float-left">   <!-- Button  Rešenje -->
              <a href="#zadatak3" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="collapse"><i>Rešenje</i></a>
              <div id="zadatak3" class="collapse">
                <p class="w3-text-grey">
                  <br>
                  Već posmatrajući grafik niza, može se izvesti zaključak da je granična funkcija ovog niza \( f(x) = 0\).
                  <br>
                  Zaista, kako je \( |f_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{n^2}\) \( \forall x\in \mathbf{R} \), biće \( \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty }{\sup_{x\in \mathbf{R}}{|f_n(x)-f(x)|}}= \) \( \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty }{\sup_{x\in \mathbf{R}}{\Bigg|\frac{1}{n^2+x^2}\Bigg|}}=  \)
                  \( \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=0\).
                  Dakle \(f_n\rightrightarrows f\).
                  <br>
                  <br>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Link to problematic page:
[http://alas.matf.bg.ac.rs/~ml05184/strana2.html](http://alas.matf.bg.ac.rs/%7Eml05184/strana2.html)

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCaMN.png)

Comment: .embed-responsive-16by9::before is taking padding and it's in %age. Try to give it in pixels as of the height of the iframe

Answer (score 1):

It is because your element `.embed-responsive-16by9::before` has padding-top that is in `%` value. Try setting `px` for larger screens

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    .embed-responsive-16by9::before {
     padding-top: 98px;
   }
}
```

Note: `1440px == 15"`

After setting the padding in px the result will be like this on bigger screens [image]

Answer (score 0):

@Viira Wow thanks!

I've edited padding setting it to the actual height of my iframe element and it works perfectly.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    .embed-responsive-16by9::before {
     padding-top: 550px;
   }
}
```